# Qr code в проекте yii

Tags: php, yii, linux

Использую в проекте вот этот qr code http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/qr-code-generator/. На локалке все ок, а перенес на сервак там не пашет. Сервак на линуксе. Сначала писало что нет доступа на запись, я дал доступ но так ничего и не создалось в той папке.. Даже не знаю в чем проблема. ошибок не выдает, просто чистая страница.
Вот этот кусок кода

```
if(!is_dir($this->filePath)) {
    throw new CHttpException(500, "{$this->filePath} does not exists.");
} else if(!is_writable($this->filePath)) {
    throw new CHttpException(500, "{$this->filePath} is not writable.");
}
```

Именно вот эта часть выбрасывает Exception,

```
else if(!is_writable($this->filePath)) {
    throw new CHttpException(500, "{$this->filePath} is not writable.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нада было GD установить)))
http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

Доступ к каталогам как давали? Попробуйте дать максимальный доступ всему проекту (/путь/ло каталога с/проетком/ mkdir 777 -R project). Если не поможет выложите сам код, который не работает.

Comment: mkdir если я не ошыбаюсь создание каталога. А права назначал на каталог так, chmod -R 777 uploads.

Comment: А сама папка uploads лежыт в папке img в которой хранятся изображения. Как по мне то даже не знаю есть ли смысл открывать доступ на весь проэкт.
На локалке всьо пашет без проблем.

Comment: Извиняюсь. chmod конечно. У меня например yii ругается на assets если права не проставлены. По этому сразу ставлю 777 на весь проект. Скиньте кусок кода, которым генерите QR код.

Comment: Ну я выше давал ссылку. Там розширение. А применяю во вьюшке как в примере.
<?php 
        $url = 'www.mysite.com/index.php?r=user/view&id='. $model->id;
        $this->widget('application.extensions.qrcode.QRCodeGenerator',array(
             'data' => $url,
             'filePath'=>YiiBase::getPathOfAlias('img.uploads'),
             'errorCorrectionLevel'=> 'L',
             'filename'=>'research'.$model->id.'.png',
             'displayImage'=>TRUE,
             'subfolderVar' => FALSE,
             'matrixPointSize' => 4,
            ))
                ?>

Comment: Писало is not writable.

Comment: Покажите в каком виде передаете урл. На сколько я понял вид урла здесь важен. Например: 'data'=>'http://www.mysite.com' вызовет ошибку, а 'data'=>'www.mysite.com' - нет.

Comment: > Поэтому сразу ставлю 777 на весь проект.

Не делайте так никогда. Yii, конечно, фреймворк и всю работу делает за вас, но ваши ошибки за вас он не исправит. Вы, как специалист, должны четко знать, в какие папки какой доступ должен предоставляться.